# Split string with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
EXAMPLE|abcd|[!PAGE|title]
```

I want to split it like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => EXAMPLE
    [1] => abcd
    [2] => [!PAGE|title]
)
```

How to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: depends. do you have more details as to requirements? from your example, you could use substring with fixed sizes...

Comment: If you're php 5.3+, this would be the best option IMO:http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: @DarkNeo, it doesn't have to be CSV.

Comment: It's CSV-style, you can define delimiter and enclosure characters so it suits your example

Comment: @a3f enclosure must be a single character so str_getcsv wont work here

Comment: @Gordon replace '[' with ']' and use latter as enclosure

Comment: @a3f yeah, but that's not what the OP got there, so not an option.

Comment: @DarkNeo Watch my solution again, I've updated it :)

Comment: Why you think it's not an option ? I'd prefer it over regex if i had a similar problem

Comment: @a3f Can you give an example? I've tried use str_getcsv but I wasn't got what I need.

Comment: posted a solution with str_getcsv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eB0cD3)

If you don't need anything more than you said, is like parsing a CSV but with `|` as separator and `[` as `"` so: `(\[.*?\]+|[^\|]+)(?=\||$)` will do the work I think.

EDIT: Changed the regex, now it accepts strings like [asdf]].[]asf]

Explanation:

1. `(\[.*?\]+|[^\|]+)` -> This one is divided in 2 parts: (will match 1.1 or 1.2)
   1.1 `\[.*?\]+` -> Match everything between `[` and `]`
   1.2 `[^\|]+` -> Will match everything that is enclosed by `|`
2. `(?=\||$)` -> This will tell the regular expression that next to that must be a `|` or the end of the string so that will tell the regex to accept strings like the earlier example.

Answer (score 2):

use this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/fE9zZ3) `(?<=\||^)(((\[.*\|?.*\])|(.+?)))(?=\||$)`

```
(?<=\||^) Positive LookBehind

    1st alternative: \|Literal `|`

    2nd alternative: ^Start of string

1st Capturing group (((\[.*\|?.*\])|(.+?))) 

    2nd Capturing group ((\[.*\|?.*\])|(.+?)) 

        1st alternative: (\[.*\|?.*\])

            3rd Capturing group (\[.*\|?.*\]) 

                \[ Literal `[`

                . infinite to 0 times Any character (except newline) 

                \| 1 to 0 times Literal `|`

                . infinite to 0 times Any character (except newline) 

                \] Literal `]`

        2nd alternative: (.+?)

            4th Capturing group (.+?) 

                . 1 to infinite times [lazy] Any character (except newline) 

(?=\||$) Positive LookAhead

    1st alternative: \|Literal `|`

    2nd alternative: $End of string

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: It works too, but I think that variant by @Javier better :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DarkNeo, Javier's regex does not work when string contains separated `[` or `]`, f.e. `EXAMPLE|abcd|[!PAGE|title]]`

Comment: can you explain what it does instead of just throwing fish at the OP

Comment: @Gordon follow the link, it contain great description

Comment: @burning_LEGION I dont want to follow the link. I want you to improve the answer so it actually teaches people something. Putting a link to a reference is fine, but someone new to Regex will still have a hard time making sense of your pattern. Thus, I am asking you to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, you could use `(\[.*?\]|[^|]+)`.

```
preg_match_all("#(\[.*?\]|[^|]+)#", "EXAMPLE|abcd|[!PAGE|title]", $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);

// output:
Array
(
    [0] => EXAMPLE
    [1] => abcd
    [2] => [!PAGE|title]
)
```

Comment: @Supericy - I think preg_split would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @wojciechzylinski It's matching everything between `|` characters, so using preg_split with this pattern would just return a bunch of `|`'s.

Comment: Yes, I know. Your regex works fine and I upvoted your answer. I just think it would be better to use preg_split (with modified regex). More of a preference than issue.

Answer (score 0):

A Non-regex solution:

```
$str = str_replace('[', ']', "EXAMPLE|abcd|[!PAGE|title]");
$arr = str_getcsv ($str, '|', ']')
```

If you expect things like this "[[]]", you would've to escape the inside brackets with slashes in which case regex might be the better option.

Answer (score -5):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$array= explode('|', $string);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => EXAMPLE
    [1] => abcd
    [2] => [!PAGE
    [3] => title]
)

Comment: This will break the part in brackets as well.

Comment: Okay. Well, put them back together then.